# Extending native Array object, length enumerable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, prototype

Here is my attempt

```
var extend = function(base, sub) {
    sub.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
};

MyArray = function() {
    Array.call(this, arguments);
};

extend(Array, MyArray);

var arr = new MyArray();

arr.push(1);
arr.push(2);
arr.push(3);

console.log(arr);

for (var i in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(i + " => " + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

And the output it is generating (running this in node)

```
{ '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, length: 3 }
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 3
length => 3
```

I assume by calling `Array.call(this, arguments)`

I would be passing off the construction of the object to the native constructor, which should handle the length as not enumerable.

When switching to `new Array()` it generates the following output.

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 3
```

The general question is why the differences in the resulting object, and more specifically, why is the length property made enumerable?

Comment: Extending the native Array is troublesome. If you could perhaps encapsulate an array in your MyArray class, it would be a lot easier.

Comment: Sure, this is a slightly academic question to define what "troubleshome" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume by calling `Array.call(this, arguments)` I would be passing off the construction of the object to the native constructor, which should handle the length as not enumerable.

No. [EcmaScript 5 does not allow to subclass `Array`](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) - in a controlled environment like node you can only use the `var arr=[]; arr.__proto__=mycustomprototype;` hack.

[`Array.call(this)`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.1) unfortunately does not work. It returns a new array, which is assigned to nothing, but it does not do anything on `this`. You can check by `this !== Array.call(this)`.

So how did you get a `length` property on your custom object? [`push`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.7) did create it. It saw the inherited `Array.prototype.length` property (`0`), so after inserting the number it did assign `arr.length = 1` which created an enumerable property.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is a good practice to avoid inheriting from standard classes. The reason for that is that there are some properties such as length, for example, that operate specially on objects that are marked internally as true arrays.

Objects created using the Array constructor or the array literal expression  have that internal property set to "Array". Instances of the Array subclass have the the value of "Object" for the [[Class]] property. Try the following

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(arr); // "[object Object]"
```

whereas

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([]); // "[object Array]"
```

That means that some of the Array properties are going to lose their default behavior.